Smooth playback of real-time AMR audio packets in web client
I'm developing a real-time PTT (Push-to-Talk) system. The server receives compressed AMR packets, decompresses them to WAV format, and sends them to a web client. However, the audio playback on the client isn't smooth. I suspect it's because each packet sent to the client includes the entire WAV header, causing interruptions.
How can I optimize this process for smoother real-time audio playback? What's the best practice for handling streaming audio in this scenario?
Here's a snippet of what I'm currently working with on the client side:
class AudioPlayer {
    constructor(websocketUrl) {
        this.socket = new WebSocket(websocketUrl);
        this.audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
        this.socket.onmessage = (event) => this.handleAudioData(event.data);
    }

    async handleAudioData(data) {
        const arrayBuffer = await data.arrayBuffer();
        const audioBuffer = await this.audioContext.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer);
        this.playAudioBuffer(audioBuffer);
    }

    playAudioBuffer(audioBuffer) {
        const source = this.audioContext.createBufferSource();
        source.buffer = audioBuffer;
        source.connect(this.audioContext.destination);
        source.start();
    }
}

Thanks in advance for any help or insights!

WAV is possibly the worst format to send to a browser.   Instead of converting to WAV, try OGG instead.

You need to figure out what the problem is: network from server to web client? Client decoding the wav? Buffering? Decoding? Native browser Audio supports "playback formats" but you should probably use a WebRTC audio stream direct from server to client to get the best possible audio. If the client has enough battery you should ensure your RTC keeps sending packets to keep the connection alive and healthy.
